# Can I create a custom Authorization policy that I can pass in fields received from my controller method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to have the parameter I receive in the controller from a client be used to authorize my "POST" methods used in my projects(Users can only edit projects they are assigned to). UserIds will live on the project so I need to fetch the project and verify the current user id is in the project.

```
// I want to modify my policy below where I can use "projectId". ProjectId is dynamic and passed in from a ajax call
[Authorize(Policy = "CanModifyProject")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveWorker(var projectId, workerModel worker)
{
// Code here....
}
```

My policy

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CanModifyProject requirement)
        {
            bool isSuperAdmin = context.User.IsAdmin();
            bool isAdmin = context.User.IsAdmin();
            var currentUserId = context.User.GetUserId();

            // I NEED TO HAVE THE DYNAMIC PROJECT ID here recieved by "POST" methods
            int projectId = 0;

            // Check to see if the project has the assigned User
            var projectUserIsAssigned = this.projectRepository.ProjectIsAssignedToUser(projectId currentUserId);

            if (isSuperAdmin || isAdmin && projectUserIsAssigned)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
```

How can I access my ProjectId in my post method ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization phase is fairly early in the request processing pipeline, before executing the action. So no view model is bound yet (by model binding). I would use an `IActionFilter` or `IAsyncActionFilter` for this purpose. There you can access the `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments` to get the bound parameter you want for your custom authorization.

Here I would like to try solving it the way you want with the code usually executed in the scope of `IAuthorizationFilter` or `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` (there is another place in which it's executed in the `AuthorizationMiddleware`). With this approach, it's limited in how you get the action argument value. It should be plainly accessible via some key and the raw value we get is of course a string. As in your specific requirement, it's just a parameter of `int` which can be sent via form-data or query string from the client.

The point here is we can get such a raw value using a `CompositeValueProvider`.
The code should say it all:

```
//inject IOptions<MvcOptions> into your CanModifyProject requirement class
//name it as _mvcOptions

protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CanModifyProject requirement) {
        bool isSuperAdmin = context.User.IsAdmin();
        bool isAdmin = context.User.IsAdmin();
        var currentUserId = context.User.GetUserId();

        var projectId = 0;
        //get projectId
        if(context.Resource is ActionContext ac && 
           ac.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor ca)
        {
            //match only the related controller method
            if(ca.ControllerTypeInfo == typeof(YourController) && 
               ca.MethodInfo.Name == nameof(YourController.SaveWorker)) {

                //create the composite value provider
                var valueProvider = await CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ac, _mvcOptions.Value.ValueProviderFactories);

                //get the raw id (as string)
                var id = valueProvider.GetValue("projectId").FirstValue ?? "";
                //parse your projectId here
                int.TryParse(id, out projectId);
            }                  
        } 

        //your remaining code (unchanged)
        //...
}
```